# How to decrease the number of tiny islands in Smart UV Project for photogrammetry models?

Tags: uv, photogrammetry

Smart UV project is making some pretty terrible UVs for my photogrammetry scans:

[image: Object view.]
[image: Edit view.]
[image: Zoomed out view of UV.]

Lots and lots of tiny islands.

[image: Smart UV project settings.]

I already tried changing the smart UV project settings.  I need margin at .1 so I can edit sections in Photoshop later.  Changing area weight doesn't do anything.

[image: Flat mesh selection.]
[image: Flat mesh UV.]

Flat sections of mesh translate to UV great.

[image: Complex mesh selection.]
[image: Complex mesh UV.]

But anything slightly complicated and BAM, tiny UV islands everywhere.

Surely there is a better way to do this.  Any ideas?  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The cleanest way would be to separate the objects, retopo and then UV unwrap.

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues editing your UV layout in an external program, you might keep a small margin and increase the exported UV layout's resolution instead:

[image: demo picture]

Also, if your output render engine supports multiple UV sets for one object, you might just make several UV unwraps which each gives more pixels to different areas. You could have one UV Map for the house for example, and one for the other parts.

[image]

For rendering in Cycles, you will just have to use the Input → UV Map in order to specify which UV Map to use in your shader. You can have one node for each UV Map you need:

[image]

Or play it the "Divide and Rule" way: 
Just split your mesh into different smaller objects and give them what they need in UVs and textures.
In order to split: go in edit mode, select the mesh you want to split, then hit <kbd>P</kbd> → Separate Selection. What you selected will be sent into a new object. Repeat as much as you need.

Comment: Hmm there's a thought.  I have a hard limit on texture resolution of the end product, but maybe I could start with a very high resolution texture, edit it in photoshop, then scale it down.  Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer, and this might give you the trick you need. Check it out.